# Gatsby and Strapi: Specific instances of data queried from Gatsby return null, despite existing in Strapi

Tags: gatsby, netlify, strapi

I am querying data from Strapi using Gatsby. Certain specific "where" queries are returning null, despite existing in the CMS. This is happening to many instances of this data (estimated about 20 out of 120 pages.

For example, this page is failing to render at all: https://flutterbyexample.com/lesson/bring-it-all-together

Compare that to this: https://flutterbyexample.com/lesson/wrap-the-pegs-in-animated-widgets

Finally, when I ping the API directly, the content *does* exist. **So, I think this is a gatsby issue.**

There are no errors in the console or when running `gatsby build` locally. `gatsby clean` doesn't help either.

---

Background info:

- the data I'm querying from Strapi is under a collection called `lesson`
- Strapi is deployed to Heroku, and this portion of the API is public

---

Gatsby queries:

This query does not work:

```
{
  strapiLesson(slug: {eq: "bring-it-all-together"}) {
    id
    author {
      email
      username
      twitter
    }
    content
    updated_at(formatString: "dddd, Do of MMMM, YYYY")
    slug
    strapiId
    title
    tutorial {
      category
      title
    }
  }
}


RETURNS:
{
  "data": {
    "strapiLesson": null
  }
}
```

For posterity, a successful query:

```
{
  strapiLesson(slug: {eq: "about-dart"}) {
    id
    author {
      email
      username
      twitter
    }
    content
    updated_at(formatString: "dddd, Do of MMMM, YYYY")
    slug
    strapiId
    title
    tutorial {
      category
      title
    }
  }
}


RETURNS

{
  "data": {
    "strapiLesson": {
      "id": "Lesson_1",
      "author": {
        "email": "eric@ericwindmill.com",
        "username": "Eric Windmill",
        "twitter": "ericwindmill"
      },
      "content": "...",
      "updated_at": "Sunday, 12th of July, 2020",
      "slug": "about-dart",
      "strapiId": 1,
      "title": "About Dart",
      "tutorial": {
        "category": "Dart",
        "title": "Getting Started with Dart"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Again, if I Ping the API directly for the `lesson` with the slug `bring-it-all-together`, I get this JSON. So, I know the API works.

```
[
  {
    "id": 121,
    "title": "Bring it all together",
    "author": {
      "id": 1,
      "username": "Eric Windmill",
      "email": "eric@ericwindmill.com",
      "provider": "local",
      "confirmed": true,
      "blocked": false,
      "role": 1,
      "twitter": "ericwindmill",
      "bio": "Creator of Flutter by Example. Author of Flutter in Action. Located in lovely Portland, Oregon.",
      "created_at": "2020-07-06T19:22:22.529Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-07-11T16:32:52.601Z",
      "profile_image": null
    },
    "content": "...",
    "slug": "bring-it-all-together",
    "tutorial": {
      "id": 9,
      "title": "Custom Animation: Progress Indicator",
      "category": "Flutter",
      "author": 1,
      "created_at": "2020-07-24T16:49:09.645Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-07-24T16:50:23.886Z"
    },
    "created_at": "2020-08-06T15:24:05.612Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-08-06T15:24:05.624Z"
  }
]
```

The final, funny thing here, to re-enforce that Strapi seemingly works, is that when I query for `tutorial`, which has a one-to-many association with `lesson`, the meta-info about the `null` lesson is indeed there. This is the GraphQL query:

```
{
  strapiLesson(slug: {eq: "bring-it-all-together"}) {
    id
    author {
      email
      username
      twitter
    }
    content
    updated_at(formatString: "dddd, Do of MMMM, YYYY")
    slug
    strapiId
    title
    tutorial {
      category
      title
    }
  }
  strapiTutorial(title: {eq: "Custom Animation: Progress Indicator"}) {
    lessons {
      author
      created_at
      id
      slug
      title
      tutorial
      updated_at
    }
  }
  strapiTableOfContents {
    contents
  }
}

RETURNS:

{
  "data": {
    "strapiLesson": null,  // <--- lesson data should be here
    "strapiTutorial": {
      "lessons": [
        {
          "author": 1,
          "created_at": "2020-07-24T17:01:01.352Z",
          "id": 83,
          "slug": "build-the-example-app-boiler-plate",
          "title": "Build the example app boiler-plate",
          "tutorial": 9,
          "updated_at": "2020-07-24T17:01:01.364Z"
        },
        {
          "author": 1,
          "created_at": "2020-07-24T17:41:14.728Z",
          "id": 86,
          "slug": "tween-by-example",
          "title": "Tween by example",
          "tutorial": 9,
          "updated_at": "2020-07-24T17:41:14.736Z"
        },
        {
          "author": 1,
          "created_at": "2020-07-24T17:42:02.927Z",
          "id": 88,
          "slug": "wrap-the-pegs-in-animated-widgets",
          "title": "Wrap the Pegs in AnimatedWidgets",
          "tutorial": 9,
          "updated_at": "2020-08-05T19:12:37.252Z"
        },
        {
          "author": 1,
          "created_at": "2020-07-24T17:40:51.308Z",
          "id": 85,
          "slug": "tween-and-animation-controller-classes",
          "title": "Tween and AnimationController classes",
          "tutorial": 9,
          "updated_at": "2020-07-24T17:40:51.317Z"
        },
        {
          "author": 1,
          "created_at": "2020-07-24T17:00:31.617Z",
          "id": 82,
          "slug": "progress-indicator-intro-and-overview",
          "title": "Intro and Overview",
          "tutorial": 9,
          "updated_at": "2020-07-24T17:00:31.627Z"
        },
        {
          "author": 1,
          "created_at": "2020-08-06T15:24:05.612Z",
          "id": 121,
          "slug": "bring-it-all-together",          // <-- the data exists
          "title": "Bring it all together",
          "tutorial": 9,
          "updated_at": "2020-08-06T15:24:05.624Z"
        },
        {
          "author": 1,
          "created_at": "2020-07-24T17:41:39.161Z",
          "id": 87,
          "slug": "using-tweens-and-intervals",
          "title": "Using Tweens and Intervals",
          "tutorial": 9,
          "updated_at": "2020-07-24T17:41:39.173Z"
        },
        {
          "author": 1,
          "created_at": "2020-07-24T17:01:38.537Z",
          "id": 84,
          "slug": "custom-widget-peg",
          "title": "Custom Widget: Peg",
          "tutorial": 9,
          "updated_at": "2020-07-24T17:01:38.546Z"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unbelievable. Such a stupid mistake. Wasted hours.

In my `gatsby-config` configuration of `gatsby-source-strapi` plugin, I had the query limit set to 100.